# Current flow rates in capacitors connected in series

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, capacitance

In the following question, the capacitor $C_2$ is is initially charged to a potential difference to $2\epsilon$, when the switch was open. The solution to the problem takes the rate of change of charge on both capacitors to be equal when the switch is closed.

[image]

How can you be certain of this? Wouldn't there be two currents, one flowing in the isolated system and another flowing in the part of the loop with the cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as there's no interference from the outside, like an induced current, the current flowing in to any point on the circuit will be equal to the current that flows out.

The current will be the same because when current flows onto a capacitor, the plate into which it is flowing begins charging up, creating an electric field towards the second plate, pulling negative charge onto it. The action of negative charge gathering up on that plate is also a current, and it is in the direction past that plate, so this re-creates the current on that side, in a reversed sort of way.

So basically, one charge entering the plate of a capacitor, causes an opposite charge to flow into the other plate, creating the current that flows on the other side. This means the current that flows on the circuit *is* caused change of the charge on the capacitors changing. The current from the power source flows according to the capacitances of the two capacitors, and the change in the charge of one triggers the change for the other, as they get more and more charged, the current on the whole circuit steadily decreases.

Comment: Got everything but the start of the last paragraph; can you go over "So while one capacitor discharges, the other one starts charging,..." again?

Comment: Actually that's not accurate! My bad, I thought the power source was facing the other way, and we don't know how the capatitor $C_2$ is initially charged, which of its plates have the high/low potentials. If the bottom plate is the negatively charged one, both capacitors will charge. If the bottom plate is the positively charged one, then $C_2$ will discharge and eventually recharge again in the direction the circuit 'wants' it to.

Comment: The key idea to wrap it up is, when charge enters one plate of the capacitor, an opposite charge enters the other plate. So long as they aren't full, this makes them conduct the current, as they get fuller and fuller, it gets more and more difficult for new charges to enter the plates, since the charges that are already on repel the incoming ones, making them less and less conductive until they eventually fill up.

Comment: Right, got it. By the way, I think the capacitor polarity you mentioned in the first comment might be influenced by the cell.